# Count variable and LIMIT it in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table where some results of 'myvariable' are 1 and some not. I using this code in PHP:

```
$result=mysql_query("
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `myvariable`='1' 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 15;"
);

$data=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$count = $data['total'];

echo $count;
```

As you see, I need to count `(1+1+1+1)` and get final result of this 'myvariable' in mytable but only for the last 15 rows, not for full table. 
How to do that?

---

Update, I can get this result:

```
myvariable:

1

0

1

1

1

0

0

0

0

1

0

0

0

1

0
```

But I don't need that.  I need only ONE number and that number of myvariable in this case must be 6.

Calculating last 15 numbers give you this:

> (1+0+1+1+1+0+0+0+0+1+0+0+0+1+0)=6

Only for last 15 rows not a result from whole table.

Comment: aggregate function without `group by` will return only one row, you may need a `group by` clause on a column.

Comment: You can remove LIMIT 15 to get all data

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: I know, but I don't need ALL data, just for the last 15 rows.

Comment: I think you should provide a sample data set and the desired result set.

Comment: Strawberry: ok, I have updated my question, I hope now is better to understand what I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a sub query to limit the number of rows you are dealing with to 15, and then perform the count on the result of that sub query:-

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM
(
    SELECT * 
    FROM mytable 
    WHERE myvariable='1' 
    ORDER BY id desc 
    LIMIT 15
) sub0
```

I am not sure if you want to exclude rows based on *myvariable* before or after you limit the rows to 15 so you might want to move the WHERE clause outside of the sub query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT SUM(myvariable) as total from mytable where myvariable='1' order by id desc LIMIT 15");
```

Use MySQL's [sum()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_sum) function.

As @tyteen4a03, comment suggests, please don't use `mysql_*` functions in your code.

Comment: I tried use sum() but it return me correct result of myvariable in whole table, but I need result of  myvariable in just last 15 rows. That's a problem.

Answer (score 0):

First -

```
select count(*) as total from mytable;//to get the total
$total = //store the result
```

Then -

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) as total from mytable where myvariable='1' LIMIT ".($total-15).", 15"
```

You will get the last 15 results

Comment: Can you write me complete code? I tried this, but again get result from whole table, not from just 15 last rows.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this for last 15 entries

```
"SELECT  COUNT(*) as total from mytable where myvariable='1' order by id desc LIMIT 15"
```

`order by id desc` will order your records in descending order

and the `limit 15` will limit it to only 15 entries

So you will get the result for last 15 entries

Comment: it return result of whole table, not in just last 15 rows, try it.

Answer (score 0):

You can run following query:

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT id from mytable where myvariable='1' order by id desc LIMIT 15");
$data=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$count = count($data);
```