# Count variable with limit in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, limit, counting

Nobody can answer this question?

```
$result=mysql_query("
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `total` FROM `mytable` 
WHERE `myvariable`='1' 
ORDER BY `id` DESC 
LIMIT 15;"
);

$data=mysql_fetch_array($result);

$count = $data['total'];

echo $count;
```

This count ALL result from mytable, but how I can do to count last 15 results only? It seems LIMIT 15 not work in this case?

Comment: A duplicate of your previous question, [Count variable and LIMIT it in MySql?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27099629/count-variable-and-limit-it-in-mysql). Please do not ask questions more than once.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the query you want:

```
SELECT SUM(myvariable = '1') AS total
FROM (SELECT myvariable
      FROM mytable
      ORDER BY id DESC
      LIMIT 15) AS subquery
```

This only looks at the most recent 15 rows, and counts the number of them that have `myvariable = 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want last 15 after descending order, Order by ascending and select first 15 and do descending order sort

```
select * from (SELECT *  FROM mytable WHERE myvariable='1' ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 15) ORDER BY  id DESC
```